# Problem building stripped down version of Qt 4.6.2

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to build a smaller version of Qt, I used the following configuration options:

```
./configure -qt-sql-mysql -no-qt3support -no-audio-backend -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-opengl -no-script -no-scripttools -no-javascript-jit -no-webkit -no-svg -no-multimedia -fast
```

After executing make, I eventually run into the following error:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/qtsdk-2010.02/qt/tools/assistant/tools'
cd assistant/ && make -f Makefile 
make[4]: Entering directory `/opt/qtsdk-2010.02/qt/tools/assistant/tools/assistant'
g++ -c -pipe -g -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB 
   -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_SHARED
   -I../../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../../../include/QtCore 
   -I../../../../include/QtNetwork -I../../../../include/QtGui -I../../../../include/QtXml 
   -I../../../../include/QtSql -I../../../../include -I../../../../include/QtHelp
   -I../../../shared/fontpanel -I.moc/release-shared -I.uic/release-shared 
   -o .obj/release-shared/helpviewer.o helpviewer.cpp
In file included from helpviewer.cpp:42:
helpviewer.h:51:20: error: QWebView: No such file or directory
```

Any pointers on what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is trying to build the Assistant (that is the tool you us to view Qt documentation) tool, the Assistant needs webkit. If you don't need Assistant in your application when you are distributing it, just exclude it from the build